# return type compatible issue

Tags: java, rx-java

am using `register()` in `setupRouter()` it is everything is working fine, but after version upgrade `Single<Source>` method got deprecated so am using `Completable register()`.

but in `SetupRoute()` lambda Expression `routerFactory::register` is giving error

```
Bad return type in method reference: cannot convert io.reactivex.Completable to io.reactivex.SingleSource<?>)
```

Code:

```
private Completable setupRouter() {
        return routerFactory()
                .flatMap(routerFactory -> textMessagingService().flatMap(routerFactory::register))
                .ignoreElement();
    }
   
 @Deprecated
    <C> Single<ContractDrivenRouter<C>> router(Class<C> contractClass);

 Completable register(ContractDrivenWebInterface contractDrivenWebInterface);
```

Comment: Try `flatMapCompletable` for both `flatMap` uses and remove `ignoreElement`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @akarnokd suggests in his comment, you should use `flatMapCompletable()` instead of `flatMap()`.

```
return routerFactory()
    .flatMapCompletable(routerFactory -> testMessagingService().flatMapCompletable(routerFactory::register));
```

`flatMapCompletable()` returns a Completable, so you no longer need to use `ignoreElement()` to explicitly do the conversion.

Comment: After the suggested change it is working fine, but I just want to know with this change it wont effect the existing logic right??

Comment: @abhi Correct, the logic will behave the same as before.